# FB Like Counter Not Showing Individual Results for Each Page

Tags: facebook, wordpress, facebook-like

The code below is placed in the header and called via php to every page of the website. (It's WordPress.)

The counter shows the like counts for the home page on every article. Any way to make it show the count for individual articles? [(this is the site)](http://glamourunderground.com)

```
<div id="fb-root"></div><script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1">

</script><fb:like href="http://GlamourUnderground.com" send="true" layout="box_count" width="55" show_faces="false" font="arial"></fb:like>
</div>
```

Thank you,

Tara

Comment: It would be helpful if you @Tara would also select an answer, or close, the very similar question that you asked on  http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/17785/8359 as it is still open, and it seems that you were satisfied (accepted) the answer you received here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put the permalink to the actual article in the `<fb:like>` tag, not just the home page.Try...

```
<fb:like 
     href="<?php the_permalink()?>" 
     send="true" 
     layout="box_count" 
     width="55" show_faces="false" font="arial"></fb:like>
```

This will work whenever you've called `the_post()`, e.g. on individual posts and pages and when you are in the "loop".

Comment: I tried this, unfortunately it now puts all articles at '0' except the homepage which is at '40'.

Comment: Here you can see an example of an article that should have '28' but is currently showing '0'. http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.glamourunderground.com%2F1196%2Ffind-the-one%2F

Comment: The button on http://www.glamourunderground.com/1196/find-the-one/ shows 28.  In answer to your previous comment, that's because all your "likes" thus far have specified your home page URL.

Comment: Thank you, it looks like I had to refresh the page a few times before it worked!